# Meteor template lagging one step behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, handlebars.js

Okay, so I'm running Meteor with Bootstrap 3. My page has a modal:

```
<template name="bookModal">
<div class="modal fade" id="bookModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        {{#each book}}
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-responsive modalBookImage" src="{{imglg}}"></img>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <p>maybe this is the problem</p>
      </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
</template>
```

And it feeds data to that template from a collection:

```
Template.bookModal.book = function() {
    return Books.find({_id: Session.get('bookModalID')});
}
```

And it's triggered by an event in a different template:

```
Template.home.events({
    'click .showBookModal': function(e) {
        Session.set("bookModalID", e.target.id);
        $('#bookModal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

So we're getting the id of what's clicked on, which is looked up in Books to find some information, which is fed into the template, and the modal is shown. Right?

BUT I'm running into a very strange error that I have no idea how to debug.

When I click my first '.showBookModal', an entirely blank modal shows up. Then when I click away, and click my second '.showBookModal', a modal pops up about the first thing I clicked on. This pattern continues, every time the modal opens it doesn't show the data corresponding to the new Session.get("bookModalID"), but the one that just ended.

What's going on here?

Comment: Session.get( "bookModalID") can be run in the dev console to see its value.  Also, e.target could be a child element whose event bubbled up to .showBookModal.

Comment: @user728291, yes, when I run it in the console I get the most recently clicked book id. The id that corresponds the the info I'll see the next time I open a modal.

Comment: Maybe provide more code here so others can try to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: I was just making test project to solve this issue, but Apendua was first. Anyway, sample project with solution is in [repository](https://github.com/parhelium/stackoverflow-meteor-bootstrap-modal-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### EDIT

Since Meteor 0.8 this answer is **deprecated** because in the new rendering engine (blaze) the DOM elements are not rerendered if their conent changes.

---

The problem is that your modal `div` node gets rerendered. This shouldn't happen. Only the content of the `div` can be rerendered since otherwise bootstrap routines won't work. To solve this issue either create another template:

```
<template name="bookModalContent">
    ...
</template>
```

so that you can write:

```
<template name="bookModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      {{> bookModalContent}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

or `{{#isolate}}` a part of your `bookModal` template which is going to be reactive:

```
<template name="bookModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      {{#isolate}}
        {{#with book}}
          ...
        {{/with}}
      {{/isolate}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Could you point me towards some documentation of {{#isolate}}? It works, but I have no idea what it's doing.

Comment: You can think about `{{#isolate}}` as an anonymous template with no helpers nor events attached. The whole thing is described [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#isolate).

Comment: @apendua: Have they changed the naming? The link no longer works and #isolate is never mentioned.

Comment: @oligofren I think that `{{#isolate}}` is now deprecated because there's not need to use it anymore. I cannot edit that link in my comment but I will edit the answer to help other people.